# Opening firefox with selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

below is part of a code i am using. It works fine except for when firefox opens it only takes up half the screen, and towards the bottom left of the screen. is there a way of altering the size of firefox when it opens?

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
#enter website into searchbox
browser.get('https://website')
#find the password element in page source
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
#input users password into website
inputElement.send_keys(password)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximize (Full screen) the Firefox window as below:

```
browser.maximize_window()
```